# Translate sweet alert title and messages using ngx translate service in the Ts file

Tags: angular, angular9

How to translate the title and text using translate service in the Ts file.
The service name is translate

```
   // Delete Address Confirmation
  onDeleteConfirm(address) {
    swal.fire({
      title: 'Are you sure?',
      // title: "'are-you-sure' | translate",
      text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
      type: 'warning',
      showCancelButton: true,
      allowOutsideClick: false,
      confirmButtonColor: this.baseService.storeTheme,
      // cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
      confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!',
      customClass: {
        confirmButton: 'confirm-button-class',
        cancelButton: 'cancel-button-class'
      },
    }).then((result) => {
      if (result.value) {
        this.deleteAddress(address);
      }
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You import your servive first, ie

```
constructor(private translate: TranslateService) { ... }
```

And then you use the service by calling the `instant` method, ie

```
this.translate.instant('property-key');
```

See [the official documentation](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core) for more on that.